# How to convert an Array to Array of Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert an Array like:

```
[ 'John', 'Jane' ]
```

into an array of object pairs like this:

```
 [{'name': 'John'}, {'name':'Jane'}]
```

Please help me to do so..

Comment: You want [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: `var arr = ['John', 'Jane']; var mapped = arr.map(name => ({name}));`

Comment: Familiarize yourself on [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the "map" function from the array:

```js
const output = [ 'John', 'Jane' ].map(name => ({name}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: About why parentheses should be added to return values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body

Comment: It's short for this.  
const output = ['John', 'Jane'].map(name=>({name: name}));

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instance method .map() on a JS list Object as follows :

```
 let list = ['John', 'Jane']
 list = list.map(x => {
    return({name: x});
                      });
 console.log(list);
```