# Convert an Array to an Array of Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

Need help for converting an array to array of object adding label.

For example I have an array:

```
data = ["data1", "data2", "data3"]
```

I want to convert and adding label.
The result expected:

```
[
   {label: "data1", value: "data1"},
   {label: "data2", value: "data2"},
   {label: "data3", value: "data3"}
]
```

Comment: use map and inside the map return  {label: e, value: e} where e is the each iteration in map

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334039/how-to-convert-an-array-to-array-of-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using `data.map(d => ({label:d,value:d}))` can do it

```js
let data = ["data1", "data2", "data3"]

let result = data.map(d => ({label:d,value:d}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const data = ["data1", "data2", "data3"];
const object = [];
data.forEach((element) => {
  const obj = { label: element, value: element };
  object.push(obj);
});
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using multiple ways, below is an implementation using `reduce`

```js
let data = ["data1", "data2", "data3"];
let result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
   acc.push({label: item, value: item});
   return acc;
   }, []);
console.log(result);
```